# VS2015 : Exception in Executing Publishing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-deployment, azure-sdk-.net

I am getting error while publishing project on shared web server (IIS).
I recently installed Azure SDK for .NET 2.9.1 on VS2015 Community Edition Update 2. And not using Azure platform to deploy websites.
I reinstalled VS2015 and Azure SDK 2.9.1 on Windows 10 machine. But Error is still same. Its not working.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was something linked to Windows 10 updates problem also. Since I did not find any solution anywhere for above error, I decided to reset OS Windows 10 Pro. Then I installed VS 2015 update 3. And it simply works now.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is happening;

- Your code is compiling against **.NET 4.6** where reference assemblies include `AzureAD.Contacts.IVsAzureADService.ProjectUserAzureAD`
- **Roslyn** compiler sees that `AzureAD.Contacts.IVsAzureADService.ProjectUserAzureAD` is available and uses it.
- Compiled app is trying to run on **.NET 4.5** where `AzureAD.Contacts.IVsAzureADService.ProjectUserAzureAD` does **not** exist.

Comment: project properties shows .Net Framework as 4.5.1. You want to say that I should set is as 4.6? I did it, but it shows same exception.